# JavaFX lineChart can't do a geometric figure

Tags: javafx, linechart

I need to do a geometric figure in a LineChart like this : [image]

The problem is to connect 1 to 2 (in the descending way). For now, I use a series for the top of the figure and another one for the bottom, but it will be better to just use one series for all, someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the solution, you can change the sorting of the lineChart with setAxisSortingPolicy and put it to SortingPolicy.NONE, it will work after